# Permutations of a 2 dimensional list in elixir

Tags: algorithm, elixir, tail-recursion

I am trying to use a simple tail recursion to retrieve all the permutations for a list of lists. the module looks like this:

```
defmodule Permutations do

  def of([], accumulator) do
    accumulator
  end

  def of([head | tail], accumulator) do
    for item <- head, do: of(tail, accumulator ++ [item])
  end
end
```

My spec for this looks like:

```
defmodule PermutationsSpec do
  use ESpec

  alias WaffleEventImporter.Permutations

  describe "of/2" do
    subject do: Permutations.of(list_list, [])

    let :list_list, do: [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
    let :expected, do: [
      [1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,1,3],[1,2,1],[1,2,2],[1,2,3],[1,3,1],[1,3,2],[1,3,3],
      [2,1,1],[2,1,2],[2,1,3],[2,2,1],[2,2,2],[2,2,3],[2,3,1],[2,3,2],[2,3,3],
      [3,1,1],[3,1,2],[3,1,3],[3,2,1],[3,2,2],[3,2,3],[3,3,1],[3,3,2],[3,3,3],
    ]

    it "returns all permutations for the 2 diensional array provided" do
      expect(subject) |> to(eq expected)
    end
  end
end
```

Unfortunately when the recursion unwinds the arrays of permutations are nested. The result of that spec is:

```
    Expected `[[[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 3]], [[1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2],
[1, 2, 3]], [[1, 3, 1], [1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 3]]], [[[2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2], 
[2, 1, 3]], [[2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3]], [[2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 2], 
[2, 3, 3]]], [[[3, 1, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 3]], [[3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 2], 
[3, 2, 3]], [[3, 3, 1], [3, 3, 2], [3, 3, 3]]]]` to equals (==) 
`[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 3], [1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3], 
[1, 3, 1], [1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 3], [2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2], [2, 1, 3], 
[2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 2], [2, 3, 3], 
[3, 1, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 3], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 2], [3, 2, 3], 
[3, 3, 1], [3, 3, 2], [3, 3, 3]]`, but it doesn't.
```

I'd appreciate any tips on how to prevent the nesting. Unfortunately flattening the output also removed the first order grouping of the combinations.

Comment: Please share a `process` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am concerned, the easiest way would be to flatten the result:

```
def flatten(list, acc \\ []) when is_list(list) do
  unless list |> Enum.all?(&is_list(&1)) do
    acc ++ [list]
  else
    list |> Enum.reduce(acc, fn e, acc -> acc ++ flatten(e) end)
  end
end
IO.inspect Permutations.of(list_list, []) |> Permutations.flatten
#⇒ desired
```

Since this is not the standard flattening, it should remain -1 level of nesting arrays. All tries to flatten the result on the fly would break the tail recursion.

---

Another option would be to use `flat_map`+`chunk`:

```
def of([head | tail], accumulator) do
  head |> Enum.flat_map(&of(tail, accumulator ++ [&1]))
end

IO.inspect Permutations.of(list_list, []) |> Enum.chunk(list_list |> Enum.count)
#⇒ desired
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is a bit unusual.

I saw your code and I remember that lists can be used as a Monad and usually the Monad List is used to do backtracking. Elixir has the statement to perform backtracking in some way: the `for` statement. To solve your problem you could do something like:

```
for i <- [1,2,3], j <- [1,2,3], k <- [1,2,3], do: [i, j, k]
```

That will generate the list of permutations you are looking for in your example. However, it is not very dynamic. When I think of dynamic, I usually think in Elixir macros. If you can create a macro that generates the code above dynamically depending on the input it would be ideal:

````
defmodule Permutation do
  @doc """
  Does the permutations over a list of lists.

  ```
  > require Permutation
  > Permutation.of([[1,2], [1,2]])
  [[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
  ```
  """
  defmacro of(list) do
    quote do: unquote(gen(list))
  end

  ##
  # Generates the for statement for the permutation depending on
  # the contents of the input list. Starting index for generated 
  # variables is 0, there are no arrows and the initial result is
  # an empty list.
  @doc false
  def gen(list) do
    gen(list, 0, [], [])
  end

  ##
  # Generates the for statement for the permutation depending on
  # the contents of the input lists.
  defp gen([], _, arrows, list) do
    gen_for(arrows, list)
  end
  defp gen([head | tail], index, arrows, list) when is_list(head) do
    var = gen_var(index)
    arrow = gen_arrow(var, head)
    list = gen_list(var, list)
    gen(tail, index + 1, [arrow | arrows], list)
  end
  defp gen(_, _, _, _) do
    :error
  end

  ##
  # Generates a variable from an index i.e for index 0 generates i0
  defp gen_var(index), do: Macro.var(:"i#{inspect index}", __MODULE__)

  ##
  # Generates an arrow for the for statement i.e. i0 <- [1,2,3]
  defp gen_arrow(var, source) do
    quote do: unquote(var) <- unquote(source)
  end

  ##
  # Generates the list from the for statement block: [i1 | [i0]]
  defp gen_list(var, list) do
    quote do: [unquote(var) | unquote(list)]
  end

  ##
  # Generates the for statement i.e.
  # for i1 <- [1,2,3], i0 <- [1,2,3], do: [i1 | [i0]]
  defp gen_for(arrows, list) do
    quote do
      for unquote_splicing(arrows) do
        unquote(list)
      end
    end
  end
end
````

I hope this helps you solve your problem. Any question about the code above, just let me know.